# Using Mina to deploy and start rails application fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, thin, mina

I use [Mina](http://nadarei.co/mina/) to deploy from my git repository to a semi production server. I say semi production because it is part of my bachelor thesis and I need to run it on a real server for performance analysis and such.

A gem I use requires to use an event-machine based webserver for the application and I wanted to use the internal thin server provided by rails.

This is what my deploy.rb currently looks like:

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
# require 'mina/rbenv'  # for rbenv support. (http://rbenv.org)
require 'mina/rvm'    # for rvm support. (http://rvm.io)

# Basic settings:
#   domain       - The hostname to SSH to.
#   deploy_to    - Path to deploy into.
#   repository   - Git repo to clone from. (needed by mina/git)
#   branch       - Branch name to deploy. (needed by mina/git)
set :domain, 'server.myuni.edu'
set :user, 'captain'
set :port, '12343'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/webpiraten'
set :repository, 'ssh://git@server.../webpiraten.git'
set :branch, 'production'

# They will be linked in the 'deploy:link_shared_paths' step.
set :shared_paths, ['log']

set :rvm_path, '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm'

# This task is the environment that is loaded for most commands, such as
# `mina deploy` or `mina rake`.

task :environment do
  # If you're using rbenv, use this to load the rbenv environment.
  # Be sure to commit your .rbenv-version to your repository.
  # invoke :'rbenv:load'

  # For those using RVM, use this to load an RVM version@gemset.
  invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-2.0.0@default]'
end

# Put any custom mkdir's in here for when `mina setup` is ran.
# For Rails apps, we'll make some of the shared paths that are shared between
# all releases.
task :setup => :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/shared/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/shared/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/shared/config"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/shared/config"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml"]
  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit 'shared/config/database.yml'."]
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up
    # instance of your project.
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    # invoke :'rails:db_migrate' # we don't use a database
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'

    to :launch do
      queue "pkill ruby" # ToDo
      queue "bundle exec thin start -e production"
    end
  end
end
```

If I run

```
mina deploy
```

It does fetch the sources deploy and precompile the assets, but the launching fails with:

```
-----> Updating the current symlink       
-----> Launching       
 !     ERROR: Deploy failed.  
-----> Cleaning up build       
       Deleting release
       Unlinking current
       OK

 !     Command failed.
       Failed with status 19
```

It seems to be the server startup, but I don't know why. If I run

```
bundle exec thin start -e production -p 3000
```

manually, it does work.

Does anyone know how to properly start the server without running into this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually pkill that was the problem. Removing/replacing that solved the issue.